# Auto-generating C++ code in a pre-build event using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, prebuild, pre-build-event

I'm trying to use a pre-build event in Visual Studio (VS 2005 to be specific) to run a Python script which will automatically generate a .cpp file.  The trouble I'm running into is that the compiler doesn't seem to know that this file is dirty and needs to be rebuilt until *after* the build has finished, which means that I need to build the solution *twice* -- once to generate this file, and then once more once so that this file actually gets compiled.

Without knowing much about the inner workings of the C++ compiler, my naive guess is that it makes a list of dirty files which need to be recompiled *before* the pre-build event runs, so it misses this auto-generated file, as it hasn't been touched until after the pre-build event.

Is there any way to inform the compiler that it needs to recompile this file if the pre-build event changes it?

Comment: I've had this problem too and was never able to solve it.  I tried setting the date into the past as part of the prebuild event, I tried setting dates on other files and deleting already compiled object files and such, nothing seemed to work.

Comment: All i have come up with is to make the pre-build executable detect that it's changed something. See this related question of mine : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528494/use-domain-specific-language-files-inside-c-project

Comment: Actually the executable i'm referring to is used in a custom build rule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use msvc 6.

Try...

```
Put the python script into the project
give it a custom build step that invokes python on it,
to create the cpp file.

Add the cpp file to your project and do a rebuild all.
```

This is how we do it with the Oracle Pro*C preprocessor.
It works fine.

Comment: I've done something similar to this with the T4 Transforms in VS2008 and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

It's not something that I've ever done but you could try invoking the compiler (cl.exe) directly from your pre-build event.